# Automatic Template Selection in Amazon Textract

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ocr, rpa, amazon-textract

I'm trying to develop a purchase order automation tool using Amazon Textract for OCR.

I have 1000+ purchase order templates. I don't want the user to search for their template from a list.

How can I enable automatic template selection when the user upload his purchase order? Or is there some tool that provide this feature?